# Grails: How to change appname in application.properties

Tags: grails

How to change `app.name` for a `groovy grails` application? I have a default value configured in `application.properties` metadata file.

I am using grails 2.1.1 version. I have tried using `Metadata` class to change the app.name, but failed to set value.

And I also tried setProperty("app.name", "myapp") in `BuildConfig.groovy` file. But it did not work.

Both scenarios uses the default value which is in `application.properties` file.

To stream line, I wanted to configure `app.name` in an external file. and overwrite at run time. Please let me know how can I do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of externalizing `app.name`?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the app.name in the application.properties from Config.groovy using:
appName = grails.util.Metadata.current.'app.name'

Comment: I can access it. But I wanted to change the value of app.name.

Comment: Take a look at application.properties inside the root of your grails application folder and update app.name=myApp

Comment: I want to overwrite the default value which is in application.properties with another value which I can configure externally.

Comment: Can only think of something like a shell script that comes along and updates the name to something else and then upon making war file new file is produced.. why not rename the end produce war file  to newapp.war  ?